# Geometric evolution of convex surfaces to a round sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $ = ^2$ be an embedded convex surface in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $ ∶  → ^2$ be the Gauss map for $.$ Let $_$ be the area measure on $$ and $_∗_$ the corresponding pushforward measure on the sphere, i.e., the measure assigning mass $_ (^{−1}())$ to a subset $ \subset \mathbb S^2.$ We may evolve $_∗_$ by the heat equation on $\mathbb S^2.$ Does the solution to [Minkowski’s problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_problem) imply that the resulting heat flow corresponds to a 1-parameter family of embedded convex surfaces, and if so can we provide a better description of them?

Comment: Could you write an explicit equation for the heat flow? How does this compare to other geometric heat flows?

Comment: I don't know an explicit formula for it in general. In the special case when $N_*V_M$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the area measure $V_{\mathbb S^2}$ on the sphere, however, $N_*V_M$ can be written $\rho V_{\mathbb S^2}.$ The heat equation would then be given by the usual heat equation $\rho_t = \Delta_{\mathbb S^2} \rho$ on the sphere. I'm sure this can be extended to the singular case (e.g., the case when $M$ is a polygon) by usual techniques of analysis.

Comment: Have you looked at the 1-D version?  Should be a little more explicit and at least give some ideas.

Comment: @RBega2 I agree the 1-D version would also be interesting and I have not solved it. This is a natural starting point, and I'd accept an answer in this case as well.

Comment: If you evolve that measure $N_*V_M$ by the linear heat equation with respect to the standard spherical metric, the solution converges to the constant measure. So that's probably not what you have in mind. I think you want to deform the surface $M$ in some way, but your description doesn't explain how you want to do that.

Comment: @DeaneYang That's actually exactly what I have in mind (hence the title stating convergence to a round sphere). The idea is that we can use the heat equation on the sphere to define a geometric evolution starting from the initial convex surface. Minkowski's problem is what I'm hoping will let us go from the spherical metrics back to the geometric evolution.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that I don't see how a time dependent measure on the standard sphere implies a time dependent convex surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How do you turn a scalar measure into an embedding, which is a vector-valued map? As @RBega2 observes below, it makes more sense to study a scalar PDE for the support function $h$. If so, then the measure you describe itself depends on derivatives of $h$ up to 2nd order. If you deform the support function by the density function of the measure, you get a heat equation for the support function. That has already been studied extensively.

Comment: @DeaneYang Doesn't the solution to the Minkowski problem already turn a scalar measure into an embedding (or at least a class of translations of an embedding)? That's the entire problem I've posed, as I see it. Of course the solution to my problem would be unique only up to time-dependent continuous translation.

If it has been studied extensively already all the better. In that case it would be tremendously helpful if someone might summarize the results or at least provide references as RBega2 has begun to attempt to.

Comment: Ok. I see what you’re doing. There’s only one remaining issue. The solution to the Minkowski problem assumes that the center of mass of the measure is at the origin. You have to show that if it holds for all time or find a way to work around it. This presumably works.

Comment: @DeaneYang Since evolution by the heat equation is linear and commutes with rotations, spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions. I.e. $\phi[\sum_l f_l(x)] = \sum \phi_l f_l(x)$. If the initial measure has center of mass at zero, then $f_1 = 0$ and so the evolved measure would also have center of mass at zero.

Comment: Thanks, Deane, for taking the time to review this problem. Welcome any other insight. I am realizing based on your comments that it's the translation invariance of the problem that allows the Minkowski problem and this problem to possibly admit a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little long for a comment.  I also haven't double checked things so may have made mistakes.

I'm going to treat the case of a convex curve in the plane (I imagine something similar works for surfaces).  I'm also going to assume the unit normal, $N$, is a diffeomorphism onto the circle.  In this case we have $N(p)=(\cos(\theta(p)), \sin(\theta(p)))$ where $$\theta:M\to \mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{S}^1.$$  We also think of $\theta$ as a coordinate on $\mathbb{S}^1$ (the unit circle).

In this case, I think we have that
$$
N_*V_M =\frac{1}{\kappa(N^{-1}(\theta))} d\theta,
$$
where here $\kappa$ is the geodesic curvature of the curve $M$.
So you are proposing to evolve the geometric quantity  $\psi=\frac{1}{\kappa(N^{-1}(\theta))}=\frac{1}{\hat{\kappa}(\theta)}$ by the heat equation.

In general. a function $\hat{\kappa}:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{R}$ that is positive is the curvature of a closed convex curve  (i.e. is the $\hat{\kappa}$ form above for some closed convex curve) if and only if
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos\theta, \sin \theta)\frac{1}{\hat{\kappa}(\theta)} d\theta=(0,0).
$$
This fact was observed (in the context of geometric heat flows) by Gage-Hamilton (in "The heat equation shrinking convex plane curves").
In particular, it seems that this condition is preserved by your proposed heat equation.

One final remark.  If we let
$$u(\theta)=\mathbf{x}(N^{-1}(\theta))\cdot N(\theta)$$
be the support function of the curve then it should be the case that
$$
u_{\theta\theta}(\theta)+u(\theta)=\frac{1}{\kappa(N^{-1}(\theta))}.
$$
In particular, evolving the support function by the heat equation seems to induce the same evolution as what you are proposing (in fact if you impose the condition on the curvature from above that makes sure everything comes from a closed curve then it seems like one can also go the other direction due to the invertibility of the operator in the appropriate subspace this condition defines).  The flow of the support function by the linear heat equation maybe something that has been studied before (though I don't know off the top of my head).

EDIT:  I did some more searching and the following paper [paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cag/1996/0004/0003/CAG-1996-0004-0003-a003.pdf) by Chow, Liou and Tsai, considers a linear heat flow on the support function of a convex hypersurface and relates it to the (inverse) harmonic mean curvature flow.  Perhaps this gives some ideas or at least references you can look at further.

Comment: Thank you, RBega, for this write-up. I will need to digest this later today. This is exactly what I had in mind and I'm optimistic the Chow, Liou, Tsai reference will point in the right direction.

Comment: A couple of comments: 1) The condition observed by Gage and Hamilton is in fact the necessary and sufficient condition for a solution to the Minkowski problem to exist. It was found by Minkowski himself for polytopes and later by Fenchel-Jessen and Aleksandrov for arbitrary convex bodies. So maybe it shouldn't be attributed to Gage and Hamilton. 2) I don't see why a heat equation in the curvature, which is a 4th order equation in the support function should imply a 2nd order heat equation in the support function, Any chance you could provide details?

Comment: @DeaneYang I clarified some of the issues you raised.